# Custom post type menu missing after 3.0b2 -> 3.1.2 upgrade

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I had a theme in 3.0b2 that was registering custom post types and displaying them in the admin menu just fine -- after upgrading to 3.1.2, they no longer appear in the sidebar admin menu (although they do get queried properly from the theme pages for the non-admin portions of the site).  `show_ui` is set to `true` and adding `show_in_menu` as true for good measure had no effect.  Can anyone help?

```
function balmer_init() {

//print ("Here");

register_post_type('gig', array(
    'label' => __('Gigs'),
    'singular_label' => __('Gig'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    '_builtin' => true,
    '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d',
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => false,
    'query_var' => false,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor',/* 'custom-fields' */),
    'register_meta_box_cb' => 'gig_callback',
));
}

add_action("init","balmer_init");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the errors in your registering function:

- `'Gigs'` is not part of the default language file. Either add your text domain as second parameter or drop the translation function.
- `'_builtin' => true` is wrong. Remove the parameter; it is for native post types only.
- `'supports' => array('title', 'editor',/* 'custom-fields' */),` – the comma after `editor` is a syntax error. [Turn debugging on](http://andrewnacin.com/2010/04/23/5-ways-to-debug-wordpress/) to see such errors.